# Formatting the correct path to read an xml tag using VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, path

I am trying to use the following code

```vb
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Convert_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Convert_Button.Click
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("C:\Test\Inventory.xml")
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/IXFleet/SyncData/Transaction")
        Dim product_id As String = "", product_name As String = "", product_price As String = ""
        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            product_id = node.SelectSingleNode("SiteID").InnerText
            product_name = node.SelectSingleNode("TankID").InnerText
            product_price = node.SelectSingleNode("TankNumber").InnerText
            MessageBox.Show(product_id & " " & product_name & " " & product_price)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I am trying to read the following XML data

```xml
<IXFleet>
  <SyncConfig xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SyncConfig.xsd"/>
  <SyncData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SyncData.xsd">
    <Transaction>
     <SiteID>1</SiteID>
     <TankID>1</TankID>
     <TankNumber>1</TankNumber>
     </Transaction>
  </SyncData>
</IXFleet>
```

My problem is I dont know how to format this section of code properly (specifically the SyncData part of the tag path) to actually get to the Transaction node, to read SiteID, TankID, and TankNumber

```vb
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/IXFleet/SyncData/Transaction")
```

If I manually remove the extra data (xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SyncData.xsd") in the XML file, SyncData node, and use the path as is in the VB code, it works, put the extra data back into the XML and it fails and cant find any data at all.

Any help would sure be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `NamespaceManager`. Then execute all queries with namespace prefixes and pass in the manager.

```
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("C:\Test\Inventory.xml")
    Dim nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("sd", "http://tempuri.org/SyncData.xsd")
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/IXFleet/sd:SyncData/sd:Transaction", nsmgr)
    Dim product_id As String = "", product_name As String = "", product_price As String = ""
    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        product_id = node.SelectSingleNode("sd:SiteID", nsmgr).InnerText
        product_name = node.SelectSingleNode("sd:TankID", nsmgr).InnerText
        product_price = node.SelectSingleNode("sd:TankNumber", nsmgr).InnerText
        MessageBox.Show(product_id & " " & product_name & " " & product_price)
    Next
```

Comment: I edited as shown in your code, same results...No errors generate, but no data populates the message box either. I noticed that line 4 nsmgr.AddNamespace("sd", "http://tempuri.org/SyncData.xsd") didn't include the xmlns= that was in the original XML...I tired including that but still no results.

Comment: Odd, as I've run this code with your sample data and it was working. Admitedly I used `.LoadXml` instead of `.Load` so that I could just add the string directly but that won't change things. Did you copy / paste the code?  Sure it's correctly applied?

Comment: My Bad.....I looked again and I was pointing at the wrong XML file name. I had one file name with the XLMNS in it and one without. Once I pointed at the right file, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for helping me with that. I spent hours last night trying to google the answer. Very much appreciated.